# Laravel 9.0 - Custom JWT Token

Tags: laravel, jwt

I need to generate a custom JWT Token to create a SSO link to integrate my application with a third party application, this custom token can not be related in any level with the current authenticated user.

Already tried to use `JWTFactory::class` to set the claims for my custom token and then `JWTAuth::encode($customPayload, $customKey)` but JWT is considering the authenticated user to generate the Token.

My custom key is beeing created from a string converted to base64.

My code is below:

```
$payload = JWTFactory::sub('123456')
            ->exp(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+ 60 minute')))
            ->iss('https://localhost:3001')
            ->aud('https://third.application.com')
            ->make();

$keyBytes = base64_encode('custom_key_here');

$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload, $keyBytes, 'HS256');
```

When I look into my `$payload` my custom claims are not beeing applied. Instead, I have the claims from the authenticated user.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do that?

**UPDATE**
The equivalent code in NodeJS is this:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const sharedKey = 'IUElRCpHLUthUGRSZ1VrWHAycrzV2OHkvQj9FKEgrTWI='
const keyBytes = Buffer.from(sharedKey, 'base64')

const payload = {
  sub: '123456',
  exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60),
  iss: 'https://localhost:3001',
  aud: 'https://third.application.com'
}

const token = jwt.sign(payload, keyBytes,  { algorithm: 'HS256' })
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with `JWTFactory::customClaims()->make()`. Like this:

```
$customClaims = [
            'sub' => $user->login,
            'exp' => strtotime('+ 60 minute'),
            'iss' => 'https://localhost:3001',
            'aud' => 'https://third.application.com',
        ];
$payload = JWTFactory::customClaims($customClaims)->make();

$keyBytes = base64_encode('custom_key_here');

$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload, $keyBytes, 'HS256');
```